# How to disable the publicNetworkAccess for the existing cosmos database

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Can one please let me know on How to disable the publicNetworkAccess for the existing cosmos database.

This is to make sure that the cosmos database is not exposed on the public network and will be configuring a private endpoint to restrict the access of the resource.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you not change it using Portal UI?

Comment: @GauravMantri Not finding it in the Azure portal to update this.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the az cli command: [az cosmosdb update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/cosmosdb?view=azure-cli-latest#az_cosmosdb_update) to disable the `publicNetworkAccess` for the existing cosmos database.

```
az cosmosdb update --name MyCosmosDBDatabaseAccount --resource-group MyResourceGroup --enable-public-network false
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-configure-private-endpoints#blocking-public-network-access-during-account-creation),

> To make sure that public network access is disabled even before the
> creation of private endpoints, you can set the publicNetworkAccess
> flag to Disabled during **account creation**

Here is an [example](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/101-cosmosdb-private-endpoint/)

Also note

> Note that this flag takes precedence over any IP or virtual network
> rule; all public and virtual network traffic is blocked when the flag
> is set to Disabled, even if the source IP or virtual network is
> allowed in the firewall configuration.

Comment: The question is not about enabling this feature at the time of account creation. Rather it is about changing this setting on an existing account.

Comment: yes i understand the question, i just shared the link which has all the details relevant to the question on update as well as how to setup . thanks for asking :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to update this setting on the portal. Please see the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for replying. I mapped a private endpoint to the cosmos resource and have also mapped the selected networks to the given VNet. "All networks", do get disabled as I map the private endpoint to the resource. But still when I export the template for the resource, it still says the "publicNetworkAccess" as Enabled. Where as in the template I do see that the latest configurations of the VNet and private endpoint being reflected.

Attaching the snapshot in the original question for reference

Comment: I see. I have not tried this personally but can you try after waiting for some time (say 5-10 minutes or so) and notice any difference in the generated template? In my experience, management operations on Cosmos DB (like updating account) takes some time to become effective.